Why a function is log-integrable
Let $g$ be a measurable function on the unit disk $\mathbb{T}$ with respect to the normalized Lebesgue measure $m$. Suppose that $g$ is also log-integrable, that is $\log|g| \in L^{1}(\mathbb{T})$. Consider the function $h(t)= \log(1+|g(t)|)$. I would like to know why is $h$ log-integrable. Thanks for any helpful suggestions.
The reason I would like to know why $h$ is log-integrable is because I would like to defined an outer function, which is given by the Herglotz formula (For those familiar with Hardy spaces theory). The outer function, say $O_{h}$, then has the same modulus as $h$ on the unit circle and would be bounded below.

It holds $0\leq\log(1+x)\leq x$ for $x\geq 0$. So,
$$ 0\leq h(t)=\log(1+|g(t)|)\leq |g(t)|. $$
Hence,
$$ \log |h(t)|=\log|\log(1+|g(t)|)|\leq \log|g(t)|. $$
Since $g$ is log-integrable, the last term is in $L^1$, so by monotonicity also $h$ is log-integrable.
